# TYPO3 multiple nested DatabaseQueryProcessor

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to get some records from custom tables of my own TYPO3 extension.

I have two tables: `sectors` and `contacts`.

The relation is really simple, one `sector` contains multiple `contacts`.

I'm trying to make a contact page where I would like to show `contacts` grouped by `sectors`.

So I would like to nest `QueryProcessors` together:

```
    dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = office_sectors 
        pidInList = root,-1
        recursive = 9999
        selectFields = office_sectors.*
        where = office_sectors.deleted = 0 AND office_sectors.hidden = 0
        where.inval = 1
        orderBy = office_sectors.name
        as = sectors            
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                table = office_persons
                pidInList = root,-1
                recursive = 9999
                selectFields = office_persons.*
                where = office_persons.deleted = 0 AND office_persons.hidden = 0 AND office_sectors.RELATION_FIELD = office_persons.RELATION_FIELD
                where.inval = 1
                orderBy = office_persons.name
                as = persons            
            }         
        }             
    }       
}
```

So I would like to get a list of `sectors` objects that contain all the `persons` that belong to each `office`.
I'm trying to select `persons` by filtering them in the `where` clause but I don't know how to get the outer `DatabaseQueryProcessor` output fields.

```
office_sectors.RELATION_FIELD = office_persons.RELATION_FIELD
```

Comment: While it's your own extension why won't you just use DBAL access to work with SQL? TypoScript is just an array, advanced but still.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your TS code: "where.inval" => "where.intval"? I don't know "inval".

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the suggestion regarding the DBAL, anyway I've found the solution with typoscript, the following code does the trick.
Please sorry for the "inval" error, I changed it with intval.

```
    ##########################
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = office_sectors 
        pidInList = root,-1
        recursive = 9999
        selectFields = office_sectors .*
        where = office_sectors .deleted = 0 AND office_sectors .hidden = 0
        where.intval = 1
        orderBy = office_sectors .name
        as = sectors            
        dataProcessing {
            11 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            11 {
                table = office_persons
                pidInList = root,-1
                recursive = 9999
                selectFields = office_persons.*
                where = office_persons.deleted = 0 AND office_persons.hidden = 0
                where {
                    data = field:uid
                    intval = 1
                    wrap = tt_content=|
                }                    
                orderBy = office_persons.name
                as = contacts            
            }         
        }             
    }       
}
```

The resulting array printed by "<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>" in the fluid template is this:

```
sectors => array(5 items)
  0 => array(2 items)
     data => array(29 items)
     contacts => array(11 items)
        0 => array(1 item)
        1 => array(1 item)
        2 => array(1 item)
        3 => array(1 item)
        4 => array(1 item)
        5 => array(1 item)
        6 => array(1 item)
        7 => array(1 item)
        8 => array(1 item)
        9 => array(1 item)
        10 => array(1 item)
  1 => array(2 items)
  2 => array(2 items)
  3 => array(2 items)
  4 => array(2 items)
```

I'm getting a nested array where each sectors contains its own contacts.

Thanks!!